# Can the number of selectedElements in a JTable be bound?

Tags: java, swing, binding, netbeans, javabeans

I'd like to have a label or text field that has a number representing the number of rows selected in a JTable.  I'm using Netbeans and have experimented with binding properties... There is a property on the JTable called selectedElements... seems like

```
jTable[${selectedElements.length}]
```

or

```
jTable[${selectedElements.size}]
```

should do the trick if bound to the text property of the label / textfield.  Of course, it doesn't work.  Is there a binding expression I can use to get the number of selected elements?

Answer (score 3):

I would have expected the second option to work - but doesn't. The reason probably is the following (from api doc ELProperty)

> It is very important that any bean properties addressed via a
>   ELProperty follow the Java Beans specification, including firing
>   property change notification; otherwise, ELProperty cannot respond to
>   change

the size() method of a List complies to neither of the two conditions.

one way out is to plug in a Converter (manual coding, never would use Netbeans :-)

```
    AutoBinding sizeBinding = 
        Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ,
            table, ELProperty.create("${selectedElements}"),
            countLabel, BeanProperty.create("text")
            );
    Converter<List<?>, String> converter = new Converter<List<?>, String>() {

        @Override
        public String convertForward(List<?>value) {
            if (value !=  null) {
                return "" + value.size();
            }
            return "empty";
        }

        @Override
        public List<?> convertReverse(String value) {
            return null;
        }

    };
    sizeBinding.setConverter(converter);
```

Another may be to implement and wire a BeanAdapterProvider/-Factory, as mentioned in the same doc, didn't try.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of selected rows using [`JTable#getSelectedRowCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRowCount%28%29). 
To make your label bound to this, you can add a list selection listener to the list selection model, and when the value changes, you can refresh the text on your label.

- [`JTable#getSelectionModel()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel%28%29)
- [`ListSelectionModel#addListSelectionListener(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#addListSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener%29)

I'm not sure how to use Netbeans to achieve this, but you can do this with standard Swing components.